# GO [count] vs. WHILE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I recently came across a post that suggested using GO [count] on a batch to handle massive deletes. The count argument will execute the batch a set number of times. When dealing with tens of millions of rows, this actually helped with providing feedback and I believe it also helped with performance of the deletes like this:

```
RAISERROR ( 'Processing MyHugeTable', 0, 1 ) WITH NOWAIT;
  DELETE TOP (100000)
  FROM
    MyHugeTable
  WHERE
    [TimeStamp] < @StartDate OR [TimeStamp] > @EndDate;

  SELECT
    @c = COUNT(1),
    @s = CONVERT( VARCHAR(100), COUNT(1) ) + ' left for MyHugeTable'
  FROM
    MyHugeTable
  WHERE
    [TimeStamp] < @StartDate OR [TimeStamp] > @EndDate;

  RAISERROR ( @s, 0, 1 ) WITH NOWAIT;

GO 10000
```

My question is whether anyone can tell me what the difference is between doing this `GO [count]` pattern vs. a `WHILE ( @c > 0 )` pattern. I'd like to know about efficiencies and what's going on behind the query.

I thought of running an estimated query plan to get a feel for the difference, but the `GO [count]` pattern just hangs. Is the estimated execution plan being generated for each batch cycle? When running an estimated query plan for the `WHILE` pattern, I get a plan back right away.

Is there a good use-case for the `GO [count]` pattern behavior? The only one I can think of is that I could break the query run at any time and the deletion progress up to that point will be committed but the `WHILE` (with BEGIN and END transactions) would roll back.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the work of your WHILE loop would be 'rolled back' in the way you suggest.  If you end the command during a loop, what it already did will be committed, and not rolled back.

Comment: Do you still have the link to that post suggesting using GO [count] for large deletes?

Comment: Interestingly I was looking at this topic today (batched deletes) and hit this great article from a SQL Server MVP: http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/

Comment: @TabAlleman Sorry. It was a while back. I just remember coming across it and trying it with some success.

Comment: @user1443098 Thanks for the link. That "naive" approach is where I went. The indexes in these tables are garbage and I'm not about to wait around for them to be rebuilt on millions of rows so I can utilize their benefit. It's a good approach when you have them, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GO isn't a command recognized by SQL Server. It's a batch separator used by SSMS. So, the primary difference is that the WHILE syntax is a single command issued, one time, from SSMS to SQL Server. The GO syntax, on the other hand, is SSMS resending the same command to SQL Server a specified number of times.

Comment: Accepting the answer because you pointed out the specifics of the GO command. However, it would be nice to know if there is any efficiency in it (these are scripts being executed directly in SSMS).

Comment: Using the "GO" approach, SSMS will send the same batch to the server n times, where n is the number in the "GO" stmt.  Using the WHILE approach, one batch is sent to the server.  YMMV but I'd think for most IRL uses the latter would finish faster.

Comment: @Paurian - The scripts aren't being executed in SSMS. SSMS is simply a front end application that provides a user friendly UI that makes it easy to create queries and send them to SQL Server for processing. As far as one being more efficient... When it comes to SQL Server, the answer to most questions tends to be, "it depends"... So take the following as a rule of thumb that should apply only most of the time...

Comment: With all other things held equal, WHILE loop will be more efficient than the GO #. With the while loop, everything is sent to the optimizer all in a single batch and results are rendered as fast as SQL Server can provide the data. The GO #, on the other hand, will submit each iteration of the "loop" individually, in separate batches, in serial fashion. Think of it as going to the store with your entire shopping list and and getting everything you need all at once vs making a separate trip for each individual item.

Comment: Add the fact that (as @user1443098 pointed out), the WHILE loop iterates until specific criteria are met. The GO # iterates the number of times you tell it to iterate. The use case for GO # is fairly limited when compared to While loops. Now... After all of that being said... The GO batch separator is only useful when executing ad-hoc queries from SSMS and most of those tend to be "one-offs" where you're not likely to care about an extra second or two in processing time (or even notice it) and the simplistic syntax will likely save you more in coding time than it costs you in processing time.

Comment: Thanks, @JasonA.Long for the explanation, and appreciate pointing out both that the SSMS application isn't actually running the query and that WHILE as a whole would be more efficient than the GO [number]. It brings up more questions, but that's for another Stack Overflow post.